# change http status in JAXRS MessageBodyWriter

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

My service returning response object based on computation in writeTo method i want set http status. Can you please help how i can set the http status.

```
@Provider
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public class ResponseWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<RespObject> {


        @Override
        public long getSize(RespObject resp, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                MediaType mediaType) {
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(RespObject resp, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                // Based on resp type object i want set http status here
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sounds more like something you wan to handle in a [response filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9336)

Comment: Seems to be response filter will solve problem :) Thanks for pointer.